# Склонение названий населенных пунктов: в посёлке Красногвардейском или в посёлке Красногвардейское?

Tags: склонение

В поселке Красногвардейское или в поселке Красногвардейском?

Answer (score 1):

В географической и военной литературе название не склоняется для сохранения точности названия (в поселке Красногвардейское), например: Видео **о поселке городского типа Красногвардейское в Крыму.**

В обычной литературе могут возникать  проблемы несовпадения рода в сочетании "в поселке Красногвардейском" (сравнить: поселок Красногвардейский), но без родового слово название может склоняться, если точное наименование в тексте уже упоминалось ранее, например: тюльпановое море и целебные травы **Красногвардейского.**